# - for the linux / network pundit DNS works but no internet & cannot ping externally

Tags: linux, networking, dns, internet, routing

I am on `puppy Linux` which isn't quite configured with all `Ubuntu` utilities and defaults  
this problem happens repeatedly especially after I bring my laptop out from sleep  
I don't know what I do but it will go away eventually but hanging around for quite some time and don't know what made it go back to normal again.  
 right now I am stuck  
  connecting to the internet through my `mobile hotspot`.

**problem**  
I can ping my default gateway my  `nslookup` and others suggest that `DNS name` resolution seems to happen but I cannot `ping` externally  and obviously there is no internet what seems to be the issue and how do I get online

**what I did sofar**
change to `static IP`. flush IP route and cache. turn off turn on my my Wi-Fi adaptor physically on my laptop.

 the standard DNS flush procedures do not seem to work here on puppy Linux but I haven't tried hard because DNS seems to be resolving . also I uninstall firewall right now there is no active firewall as IP tables listing will suggest

thank you Manish for your input - *since you can't go beyond default gateway the problem should be with my router* actually my router is a `hotspot`  so not many options to change stuff in my Android phone neither do I think that is the problem. I can use the same  hotspot the same client `MAC` address but through Windows connect to internet successfully. also so all other clients can access internet through my hotspot.  
here go all the
command outputs that would be needed
to troubleshoot

```
    mtt 8.8.8.8
My traceroute  [v0.93]
puppypc24185 (192.168.43.102)                          2021-08-06T09:16:22+0800
Keys:  Help   Display mo                             My traceroute  [v0.93]
puppypc24185 (192.168.43.102)                          2021-08-06T09:16:22+0800
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDevde   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit


root# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         



root# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan

root# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.203.36): 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
default         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.43.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0


root# ip route
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 metric 303 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.102 metric 303 
root# 


# Generated by dhcpcd from wlan0
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
nameserver 192.168.43.1
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
root# 
root# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:52:AF:61:5D:D5  
          inet addr:192.168.43.102  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ce52:afff:fe61:5dd5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:939 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:103106 (100.6 KiB)  TX bytes:353321 (345.0 KiB)


root# traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (142.250.67.196), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1)  1.672 ms !N  3.732 ms !N  *
root#
```

Update :connected to `Hotspot` # 2 from my AT&T phone. Same Puppy Linux connects just fine and here's  info from that

```
# from working hotspot Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

root# ifconfig wlan0  # from working hotspot
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:52:AF:61:5D:D5  
          inet addr:192.168.43.102  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16113 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16388 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10918898 (10.4 MiB)  TX bytes:2666004 (2.5 MiB)

traceroute to www.google.com (142.250.67.164), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1)  1.742 ms  1.265 ms  1.297 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  192.168.126.1 (192.168.126.1)  33.108 ms  41.645 ms  29.127 ms
 4  172.30.43.1 (172.30.43.1)  30.081 ms  58.142 ms  *
 5  *  118.185.45.78 (118.185.45.78)  32.250 ms  42.083 ms
 6  74.125.48.70 (74.125.48.70)  23.253 ms  32.475 ms  25.334 ms
 7  10.252.213.190 (10.252.213.190)  21.905 ms  10.252.227.158 (10.252.227.158)  22.106 ms  10.252.182.222 (10.252.182.222)  28.094 ms
 8  108.170.248.209 (108.170.248.209)  41.186 ms  33.617 ms  142.250.214.102 (142.250.214.102)  38.946 ms
 9  142.250.227.73 (142.250.227.73)  34.139 ms  108.170.248.210 (108.170.248.210)  41.999 ms  142.250.227.73 (142.250.227.73)  44.733 ms
10  bom12s07-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.67.164)  106.250 ms  48.687 ms  30.848 ms
root#
```